# CSS Selector for external Link Tracking (Outbound Tracking ) For AMP

Tags: css

Looking to track external Link Click on Pages, I tried to used this for CSS Selector external tracking

I used this CSS selector:  `a:not([href*="example.com"])` and also tried this CSS selector: `a[href]:not([href^="example.com"]`, [href$="\#"]) but does not tracking when I am clicking external does not tracking , CSS Sector does not working

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Berto99 For External Link - https://www.screencast.com/t/74VS6cebw, https://www.screencast.com/t/gJviwiWG9ocR